# Como renderizar um mesmo componente várias vezes no React?

Tags: javascript, array, react, react-native

Estou tentando fazer uma lista com um um componente sendo repetido determinada vezes.

Pra ser mais claro, tenho uma `ScrollView` e um componente próprio `PutANumber`. Preciso que a `ScrollView` tenha uma quantidade pré-definida de componentes `PutANumber`.

Literalmente seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```xml
<ScrollView>
  /* Alguma expressão que coloque uma quantidade
     específica de componentes PutANumber... */
</ScrollView>
```

Considerando que a quantidade de `PutANumber` necessária seria 5,
o código escrito explicitamente seria:

```xml
<ScrollView>
  <PutANumber/>
  <PutANumber/>
  <PutANumber/>
  <PutANumber/>
  <PutANumber/>
</ScrollView>
```

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4):

Como um componente React nada mais é do que mera chamada à `React.createElement`, é a mesma coisa que criar um array com N elementos.

Um exemplo simples: criar um array com 5 booleanos `true`:

```js
const arr = Array.from({ length: 5 }).map(() => true);
console.log(arr);
```

Claro, no exemplo acima daria para utilizar o [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), mas como veremos no exemplo a seguir, [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) é mais ideal no caso específico do React, uma vez que somos obrigados a passar a propriedade `key` — o qeu nos obriga diferir, mesmo que minimamente, cada elemento.

No React então não ficaria muito diferente:

```js
function PutANumber() {
  return <div>Componente PutANumber.</div>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, index) => (
        <PutANumber key={index} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

O `map` teve de ser utilizado uma vez que precisamos passar uma `key` para cada componente sendo renderizado via array. A [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) explica a necessidade da propriedade `key`.

Comment: um problema a mais no site que eu estou percebendo que as perguntas tem votos positivos e a respostas não tem pontuação, isso está acontecendo de um modo geral nas perguntas e respostas, no minimo estranho. +1 na sua resposta .